# What are the major differences between the different versions of the PS3?

Tags: ps3, version-differences

Recently, I've preordered myself a PS3 game. Now I think it's a good time for me to purchase a PS3 to play it on! Now, I was going to go with what I assumed to be a normal setup, but then I was told about a sale on a "Slim" version, which seemed like a good deal. But I imagine that in being Slim, it has some corners cut, so there's going to be differences.

What are the actual differences between the different versions of the PS3? And how many are there, anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually the only version being produced is the slim version ... you won't find a new -fat- version anymore... (unless someone sells them like diamonds).
Anyways.
The difference among the new models (slim ones) is based in their hard drive size. The actual versions are 120Gb and 250Gb ... but beware, this month Sony Japan will release new Slim versions in white color with higher high drives ... !!!

You can read further information on technical differences here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS3#Model_comparison

Comment: Watch out if PS2 backward compatibility is a concern as only the oldest systems provide it.

Comment: That is also something important to notice ... not every OLDEST system is able to do PS2 backward compatibility.

Comment: Well, my pre-order just arrived today (and it was worth every bit of cash spent), so I suppose it's about time to really put this information to good use. Thank you much!

Comment: Ah, good ole Sony. First lure your customers with backwards compatibility and other OS, then...