# Kinect Joy Ride: Playing the game with wireless controller

Tags: controllers, kinect, kinect-joy-ride

Is it possible to play [Kinect Joy Ride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect_Joy_Ride) with wireless Xbox 360 controller? I don't own Kinect yet.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you'd buy the game before buying the Kinect? The game has Kinect in its title, so color me confused.

Comment: No particular reason. If it can be played with wireless controller as well, I may think about buying it.

Comment: Added kinect tag is all.

Comment: @Raven There's absolutely [nothing wrong](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/117/what-are-the-major-differences-between-the-different-versions-of-the-ps3 "I did it with a 360 game years before the PS3, too!") with buying games before having the right hardware. If anything, it builds anticipation. ♪

Comment: @Grace Note -- oh, don't get me wrong. It's just the question struck me as an odd one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If a Kinect game has the purple case with Kinect on it (which Joy Ride does), you have to have the sensor to play the game, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect#Software

Answer (score 3):

No.  Though it was originally planned to be a [completely free game with controller support](http://kotaku.com/5274698/xbla-getting-free-dlc+supported-racing-game), they changed their minds; it is now a [retail Kinect-only title](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/article.php?id=249663).

Comment: That's actually pretty funny. In a "corporate sellout" depressing sort of way. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've only played the demo version of it that came with the Kinect, and it doesn't appear you can do it with a controller.

Frankly, however, this game would be extremely lame if it wasn't for the motion-sensing no-controller aspect of it. This game is absolutely centered around that gimmick and really doesn't let you control too much of the game. Acceleration and Braking is all controlled by the AI, the controls you are given are limited to steering, speed-boosting, and a few tricks on jumps.